# Master Page Header Navigation

Tags: asp.net, web

I need pointers, and I know someone asked this before but I like a fresh start :)
I want to make a master header for my website, to be accurate I want to make my navigation as a master page and i need pointers where to start and with what "tools" to start working on it. Thanks :)

Comment: if you know someone has asked this, why are you asking again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of examples on the internet. Look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581781.aspx), if you don't understand something specific then you should ask.